# Converting tf1 to tf2 for Google ML Course's Recommendation Systems, Exploding Loss

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0, recommendation-engine

[image]

I want to convert this notebook written in tf1 to tf2, more specifically the softmax reccommender model in  [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/eng-edu/blob/master/ml/recommendation-systems/recommendation-systems.ipynb?utm_source=ss-recommendation-systems&utm_campaign=colab-external&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=recommendation-systems):

This is from the ML Course, previous steps describe [the logic](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/recommendation/labs/movie-rec-softmax-programming-exercise)

I have tensorflow version '2.3.1' on Mac OS X

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from zipfile import ZipFile
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from pathlib import Path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)

# tf.random.set_seed(42)
# np.random.seed(42)

# from urllib.request import urlretrieve
# import zipfile
# urlretrieve("http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-100k.zip", "movielens.zip")
# zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile('movielens.zip', "r")
# zip_ref.extractall()
# print("Done. Dataset contains:")
# print(zip_ref.read('ml-100k/u.info'))

# Load each data set (users, movies, and ratings).
users_cols = ['user_id', 'age', 'sex', 'occupation', 'zip_code']
users = pd.read_csv(
    'ml-100k/u.user', sep='|', names=users_cols, encoding='latin-1')

ratings_cols = ['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating', 'unix_timestamp']
ratings = pd.read_csv(
    'ml-100k/u.data', sep='\t', names=ratings_cols, encoding='latin-1')

# The movies file contains a binary feature for each genre.
genre_cols = [
    "genre_unknown", "Action", "Adventure", "Animation", "Children", "Comedy",
    "Crime", "Documentary", "Drama", "Fantasy", "Film-Noir", "Horror",
    "Musical", "Mystery", "Romance", "Sci-Fi", "Thriller", "War", "Western"
]
movies_cols = [
    'movie_id', 'title', 'release_date', "video_release_date", "imdb_url"
] + genre_cols
movies = pd.read_csv(
    'ml-100k/u.item', sep='|', names=movies_cols, encoding='latin-1')

# Since the ids start at 1, we shift them to start at 0.
users["user_id"] = users["user_id"].apply(lambda x: str(x-1))
movies["movie_id"] = movies["movie_id"].apply(lambda x: str(x-1))
movies["year"] = movies['release_date'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split('-')[-1])
ratings["movie_id"] = ratings["movie_id"].apply(lambda x: str(x-1))
ratings["user_id"] = ratings["user_id"].apply(lambda x: str(x-1))
ratings["rating"] = ratings["rating"].apply(lambda x: float(x))

# Compute the number of movies to which a genre is assigned.
genre_occurences = movies[genre_cols].sum().to_dict()

# Since some movies can belong to more than one genre, we create different
# 'genre' columns as follows:
# - all_genres: all the active genres of the movie.
# - genre: randomly sampled from the active genres.
def mark_genres(movies, genres):
  def get_random_genre(gs):
    active = [genre for genre, g in zip(genres, gs) if g==1]
    if len(active) == 0:
      return 'Other'
    return np.random.choice(active)
  def get_all_genres(gs):
    active = [genre for genre, g in zip(genres, gs) if g==1]
    if len(active) == 0:
      return 'Other'
    return '-'.join(active)
  movies['genre'] = [
      get_random_genre(gs) for gs in zip(*[movies[genre] for genre in genres])]
  movies['all_genres'] = [
      get_all_genres(gs) for gs in zip(*[movies[genre] for genre in genres])]

mark_genres(movies, genre_cols)

# Create one merged DataFrame containing all the movielens data.
movielens = ratings.merge(movies, on='movie_id').merge(users, on='user_id')

# Utility to split the data into training and test sets.
def split_dataframe(df, holdout_fraction=0.1):
  """Splits a DataFrame into training and test sets.
  Args:
    df: a dataframe.
    holdout_fraction: fraction of dataframe rows to use in the test set.
  Returns:
    train: dataframe for training
    test: dataframe for testing
  """
  test = df.sample(frac=holdout_fraction, replace=False, random_state=42)
  train = df[~df.index.isin(test.index)]
  return train, test

rated_movies = (ratings[["user_id", "movie_id"]]
                .groupby("user_id", as_index=False)
                .aggregate(lambda x: list(x)))


BATCH_SIZE = 32
EMBEDDING_SIZE = 35

class SoftmaxRecommender(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, feature_columns, **kwargs):
        super(SoftmaxRecommender, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.movie_embedding = layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns['movie'])
        self.other_features = layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns['other'])
        self.hidden_layer = layers.Dense(EMBEDDING_SIZE,
            kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal(
            stddev=1. / np.sqrt(EMBEDDING_SIZE) / 10.))
        # self.linear = layers.Dense(num_movies, use_bias=True, activation='softmax')
        # self.softmax_activation = keras.layers.Activation('softmax')


    def call(self, inputs, train=True, **kwargs):
        V = self.movie_embedding({'movie_id': inputs['movie_id']})
        inputs.pop('movie_id')
        other_fts = self.other_features(inputs)
        U = tf.concat([V,other_fts], axis=1)
        U = self.hidden_layer(U)
        logits = tf.matmul(U, self.movie_embedding.get_weights()[0], transpose_b=True)
        # logits = self.linear(logits)
        # logits = self.softmax_activation(logits)
        return logits


def custom_loss(labels, logits):
    # labels = tf.reshape(labels, [-1])
    # labels_org = labels.copy()
    labels = select_random(labels)
    # labels = tf.cast(labels, 'float32')
    labels = tf.reshape(labels, [-1, 1])
    # cce = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
    # preds = tf.argmax(logits, axis=1)
    # preds = tf.cast(preds, 'float32')
    # loss = cce(y_true=labels, y_pred=logits)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        logits=logits, labels=labels))
    return loss




years_dict = {
    movie: year for movie, year in zip(movies["movie_id"], movies["year"])
}
genres_dict = {
    movie: genres.split('-')
    for movie, genres in zip(movies["movie_id"], movies["all_genres"])
}

def select_random(x):
  """Selectes a random elements from each row of x."""
  def to_float(x):
    return tf.cast(x, tf.float32)
  def to_int(x):
    return tf.cast(x, tf.int64)
  batch_size = tf.shape(x)[0]
  rn = tf.range(batch_size)
  nnz = to_float(tf.math.count_nonzero(x >= 0, axis=1))
  rnd = tf.random.uniform([batch_size])
  ids = tf.stack([to_int(rn), to_int(nnz * rnd)], axis=1)
  return to_int(tf.gather_nd(x, ids))

def make_embedding_col(key, embedding_dim):
  categorical_col = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
      key=key, vocabulary_list=list(set(list(movies[key].values))), num_oov_buckets=0)
  return tf.feature_column.embedding_column(
      categorical_column=categorical_col, dimension=embedding_dim,
      initializer=keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal(
                                             stddev=1. / np.sqrt(embedding_dim) / 10.),
      # default initializer: trancated normal with stddev=1/sqrt(dimension)
      combiner='mean')

def make_dataset(ratings):
  """Creates a batch of examples.
  Args:
    ratings: A DataFrame of ratings such that examples["movie_id"] is a list of
      movies rated by a user.
    batch_size: The batch size.
  """
  def pad(x, fill):
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x).fillna(fill).values

  movie = []
  year = []
  genre = []
  label = []
  for movie_ids in ratings["movie_id"].values:
    movie.append(movie_ids)
    genre.append([x for movie_id in movie_ids for x in genres_dict[movie_id]])
    year.append([years_dict[movie_id] for movie_id in movie_ids])
    label.append([int(movie_id) for movie_id in movie_ids])

  features = {
      "movie_id": pad(movie, ""),
      "year": pad(year, ""),
      "genre": pad(genre, ""),
  }

  y = pad(label, -1)
  # y = select_random(y)
  # print('y.nunique:', len(np.unique(y.numpy())))

  return features, y


train_rated_movies, test_rated_movies = split_dataframe(rated_movies)
x_train, y_train = make_dataset(train_rated_movies)
x_val, y_val = make_dataset(test_rated_movies)


# create two separate DenseFeatures in model to be able to access movie_embeddings
feature_cols = {
    'movie': [make_embedding_col("movie_id", 35)],
    'other': [make_embedding_col("genre", 3), make_embedding_col("year", 2)]
}


model = SoftmaxRecommender(feature_columns=feature_cols)
model.compile(
    loss=custom_loss, optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(.1, clipnorm=1)
    # loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(.1, clipnorm=1)
)

# batch_x1 = {
#     'movie_id':x_train['movie_id'][:32],
#     'year':x_train['year'][:32],
#     'genre':x_train['genre'][:32]
#            }
#
# batch_y1 = y_train[:32]
#
# logits = model(batch_x1)
# loss = custom_loss(batch_y1, logits)
#
# batch_x2 = {
#     'movie_id':x_train['movie_id'][32:64],
#     'year':x_train['year'][32:64],
#     'genre':x_train['genre'][32:64]
#            }
#
# batch_y2 = y_train[32:64]
#
# logits = model(batch_x2)
# loss = custom_loss(batch_y2, logits)

history = model.fit(
    x=x_train,
    y=y_train,
    batch_size=32,
    epochs=10,
    verbose=2,
    validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
)
```

The above model with custom_loss that uses `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` leads to exploding gradients.

I also tried adding softmax activation in the model class and using `keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)` while doing `select_random` for labels in `make_dataset` function once and not in each batch. This approach leads to weights staying stable. If I use `keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` without adding softmax activation to the logits, loss explodes again. This might be because all values in the matrix are so small that softmax gives all of them equal probabities..

My understanding of `keras.Model` and its `call()` method might be wrong, and/or my `DenseFeatures` layer application. I understand that with exponentially increasing loss it might be that there is something wrong with the dataset, but data-preparation steps are directly copied from the original code.

I highly appreciate any help!